# "error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='"

Tags: java

Necesito encontrar solución a este error, lo he codificado en C, y me ha compilado perfecto. Pero al hacerlo en Java, no hallo el error. AYUDA.
Estos son los errores en especifico.

> E1.java:20: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='

```
boolean resa=((a>b)**<=**c)&&((b!=d)<a);
```

Donde esta negreado marca el error. (O los doble asteriscos)

> E1.java:29: error: incomparable types: boolean and int

```
boolean resd=!(((a<b)!=d)&&((a==b)&&(c<=d)));
```

Estos deben arrojar un valor 0 o 1

mis variables declaradas son estas:

```
 int a=-2;
 int b=4;
 int c=7;
 int d=-10;
```

Comment: Pues el error habla sobre tipos de datos incompatibles, ya que en un lado son enteros y en otros booleanos (true o false) lo cual me parece no es posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás comparando valores de tipos diferentes, lo que sucede es que primero se compara (a > b), lo que es falso porque a = -2 y b = 4. Entonces la siguiente comparación es si lo que resultó de esa comparación (a > b = false) es <= c, lo que resulta en incompatibilidad de datos, porque c = 7 y estas intentando comparar false <= 7, lo que no tiene sentido...

```
boolean resa=((a>b)<=c)&&((b!=d)<a);
boolean resa=((false)<=7&&((true)<-2);
//porque (a > b) retorna un dato booleano, no un entero, y los datos solo puedes compararlos con otro dato de su propio tipo
```

O sea, estas comparando un valor booleano (false) con un valor entero (7) a la izquierda de &&, y a la derecha igual, un valor booleano (true) con otro valor entero (-2).

Es como si yo te preguntara: El color verde mide 5 metros? No guardan ningún tipo de relación

Comment: Ya entiendo. Gracias por tu explicación. Me quedo muy claro este error. Gracias por la ayuda¡